# how to fix Timertask is running only once?

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I am trying to get my current location each 1 second. The method getlocationCoordinate allows to return my current lattitude and longitude.

So I implemented a timertask that is supposed to run every 1 second and return my current location, but the timertask is only running once, how can i fix this problem?

```
    Timer timer= new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();


            System.out.println(" show me current location " + getlocationcoordinate(getApplicationContext()));
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "current location" +getlocationcoordinate(getApplicationContext()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Looper.loop();


        }
    },0,1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason timer does not work as we would like,You can use a Handler

```
 private Handler handler;
 private Runnable runnable;


  handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            System.out.println(" show me current location " + getlocationcoordinate(getApplicationContext()));
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //start again
                    }
                };
```

source [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))